# Unable to dial 0800 numbers since Skype prepends country code

Tags: windows-7, skype, telephony

I've being trying to use **Skype** (version 6.9.0.106) to make a Brazilian tollfree call but it is unable to complete since Skype prepends Brazilian country code to the dialed number.

I'm dialing `0800 015 0252` and as I'm in Brazil the Brazilian flag is auto-selected. When I press the `Call` button Skype removes the first 0 and replaces it by +55

The final number is +55800 015 0252 which is not a valid number therefore the call is not completed.

How can I overcame this?

Comment: I was sure it just worked, I remember setting my Skype account to USA once so I could call the Blizzard Support Desk without having to pay an international charge by calling from New Zealand. From what I remember it just let me call it no problem. Perhaps they've changed the policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently they only support Tollfree calls to these regions:

```
France: +33 800, +33 805, +33 809
Poland: +48 800
UK: +44 500, +44 800, +44 808
USA: +1 800, +1 866, +1 877, +1 888
Taiwan: +886 80
```

[How do I dial toll free numbers (for example, +1 800, +1 866 and +1 877 number series)?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA24/how-do-i-dial-toll-free-numbers-for-example-1-800-1-866-and-1-877-number-series?frompage=search&q=toll%20free&fromSearchFirstPage=false)